# Nightwatch. Click on element with text

Tags: javascript, css, nightwatch.js

I have a problem, can`t click on web element having some unique text.
I have this structure:

```
<div class="wg-wagon-type__item"  data-reactid="10"
  <div class="wg-wagon-type__title" data-reactid="11">Text</div>
```

I try this

```
.click('.wg-wagon-type__title:contains("Text")')
```

But I have an error

```
ERROR: Unable to locate element: ".wg-wagon-type__item .wg-wagon-type__title:contain("Text")" using: css selector
```

How can I correct click on this element?

Comment: Title of your question is misspelled. Also your css selector is  not valid. :contains("Text") is jQuery, not CSS 2 or CSS3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is there any reason why you can't simply target the class `wg-wagon-type__title?`

```
.click('.wg-wagon-type__title')
```

Unfortunately there isn't a CSS selector that matches on the text of an element. However, nightwatch has the capability to run javascript on the browser via 'api.execute' and that allows you to do string matching.

Alternatively, you could use an xpath selector and use that to match the text

```
.click("//div[contains(@class, 'wg-wagon-type__title') and text()='Text']")
```