# classname with whitespaces cannot be found

Tags: javascript, css, selenium, nightwatch.js

`browser.useXpath.waitForElementVisible()` seems to have problems with (class-)names containing whitespaces. My full classname is `jstree-anchor jstree-clicked`.

The following commands succeed:

```
browser.useXpath()
    .waitForElementVisible('//a[contains(@class, "jstree-anchor")][text()="' + name + '"]', 5000)
    .waitForElementVisible('//a[contains(@class, "jstree-clicked")][text()="' + name + '"]', 5000);
```

But these fail:

```
browser.useXpath()
    .waitForElementVisible('//a[contains(@class, "jstree-anchor jstree-clicked")][text()="' + name + '"]', 5000);
browser.useXpath()
    .waitForElementVisible('//a[@class="jstree-anchor jstree-clicked"][text()="' + name + '"]', 5000);
```

How do I handle such elements when I do have to check for the full class name?

Comment: They are two separate class' if you wish to usex xpath to find a element with  more than one class see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21713280/find-div-element-by-multiple-class-names

Comment: quote from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_classname.asp): "Specifies the class name of an element. To apply multiple classes, separate them with spaces, like 'test demo'". So **there are no class names with spaces in them**, because spaces are used to separate those... solution: use properly constructed class names.

Comment: @Alessi42 The accepted answer there suggests to use exactly the same way I already tried (but failed): `waitForElementVisible('//a[@class="jstree-anchor jstree-clicked"]', 5000);` (I also tried with single quotes)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered simply spliting up the contain?

```
browser.useXpath()
    .waitForElementVisible('//a[contains(@class, "jstree-anchor jstree-clicked")][text()="' + name + '"]', 5000);
```

would become:

```
browser.useXpath()
        .waitForElementVisible('//a[contains(@class, "jstree-anchor") and contains(@class, "jstree-clicked")][text()="' + name + '"]', 5000);
```

Comment: Sorry for not being precise in my question, I want to match exactly `jstree-anchor jstree-clicked` - your answer would also match sth. like `jstree-anchor jstree-clicked foo bar`

Answer (score 0):

you can try following which uses cssSelectors:

```
 browser.useCss()
.waitForElementVisible('a.jstree-anchor.jstree-clicked[innertext="' + name + '"]', 5000);
```

Comment: It only works when I don't check for the text: `browser.useCss().waitForElementVisible('a.jstree-anchor.jstree-clicked', 5000);` But I need to check the text. The html looks like this: `<a><i></i><i></i>MyText</a>`

Comment: works neither. It looks like it isn't possible yet via css selector: [Unfortunately there isn't a CSS selector that matches on the text of an element.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42567761/1654763)